# Paypal ipn url return 401 error

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I am using codeigniter paypal library for my application
https://github.com/codexworld/paypal-library-for-codeigniter. my server is not redirecting to my notify url. i am using live server url. after analyzed with my sandbox account. i am getting 401 error. how to resolve this?
[image]

Comment: I found that the our server using authentication username and password for my site. how to send username and password also

Comment: Do you have any .htaccess asking for credentials ? Can you access the url from another server ?

Comment: Try to provide the ipn url like this : [http://user:password@yoursite.com/ipn.php](http://user:password@yoursite.com/ipn.php) for your tests